# C# Standard: rationale for "Do not provide public event member variables"?

Tags: c#, coding-style

The IDesign coding standard states "Do not provide public event member variables. Use event accessors instead."

I appreciate that there are situations where event accessors are useful (I think that `Control` uses a dictionary to only store events that are assigned to save memory). But what is the point of mandating that this boilerplate code always exists?

Edit: explicitly

```
public event EventHandler EventName;
```

vs.

```
public event EventHandler EventName { add { ... } remove { ... } }
```

[see [IDesign Coding Standard](http://www.idesign.net/idesign/download/IDesign%20CSharp%20Coding%20Standard.zip) - Coding Standards - 42]

Comment: The rational probably is the same as that behind public fields.

Comment: [see this article might help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163533.aspx) I use it sometimes to handle custom cross threading issue

Comment: True, the thing is you can make a public field into an auto-property, but I thought that the compiler basically did this for an event anyway behind the scenes.

Comment: You mean "field-like events"; yea, they are very similar in many ways to auto-props, and like auto-props they ate not the only valid implementation.

Comment: @B Tyler: Can you provide a link or example?

Comment: I've edited this to make it explicit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delegate fields ***are not events*** - they are just delegate fields. They can be (very incorrectly) inspected, nulled and invoked by external callers, whin is *contrary* to the design of events (which can only be handles by the declaring class, typically).

The encapsulation allows indirection, validation, etc; all desirable. And the cost is minimal. It would not be normal for this to impact your code's performance.

It also allows them to be used on ***interfaces***; fields cannot be declared on interfaces.

---

Edit:

The question is a little unclear, but if the question is simply field-like events vs explicit add/remove with a delegate backer... Then that is stupid. Don't add unnecessary code. Field like events would be preferred, unless there are enough events to warrant an EventHandlerList implementation.

In particular, the 4.0 compiler does the thread-safety very sensibly now (this was not the case historically).

Comment: -1: @Marc: I think the IDesign coding standard is not talking about delegate fields, neither is the OP.

Comment: Is this relevant here? The coding guideline that was quoted doesn’t talk about *delegates* but events. Or did they just use a misleading terminology?

Comment: @Marc: It is talking about `public event EventHandler EventName;` vs. `public event EventHandler EventName { add { ... } remove { ... } }`

Comment: @Konrad @Daniel a "public member variable" (question) is aka a public field. But is this actually talking about something else?

Comment: @Marc: a "public event member variable" (question) is **not** a delegate field. It is this: `public event EventHandler EventName;`

Comment: @Daniel But then the terminology would *also* be false (the latter is a “custom event”). I think we can conclude that either way the terminology is wrong and what they *probably* meant were delegate fields. But since they can’t even get the terminology right, why heed them?

Comment: @Daniel @Konrad expanded to discuss that too. But I maintain: a "member variable" is a ***field***.

Comment: @Marc: Removed downvote, because I agree with your edit. @Konrad: Agree, terminology could be clearer.